# PHP can I add line numbers to file_get_contents()

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, customization

I have a private custom plugin that I just use on my multiple sites, and since I do a lot of debugging I find it easier to include the wp-config.php file contents in the admin area to ensure I have enabled/disabled debugging properly. Now I am training other designers to help with debugging, so I want to include line numbers similar to the theme/plugin editor. I retrieve the contents of the wp-config file using the `file_get_contents()` function. Is there a way I can add line numbers to this output?

Here is my function that gets the wp-config file contents:

```
function eriWpConfig(){
    $wp_config = FALSE;
    if ( is_readable( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' ) )
        $wp_config = ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php';
    elseif ( is_readable( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php' ) )
        $wp_config = dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php';

    if ( $wp_config )
        $code = esc_html( file_get_contents( $wp_config ) );
    else
        $code = 'wp-config.php not found';

    echo '<pre class="code"
            >Installation path: ' . ABSPATH
          . "\n\n"
          . $code
          . '</pre>';
}
```

**EDIT:**
Per Q Studio's suggestion, I tried the following and I'm just returning Line 0 at the beginning of the output.

```
if ( $wp_config ) {
        $string = file_get_contents( $wp_config );
        $lines = explode('\n', $string);
        $modified_lines = [];
        $line_count = 0;
        
        foreach($lines as $line){
            $modified_lines[] = 'Line '.$line_count.' '.$line;
        }
        
        $code = esc_html( implode('<br>', $modified_lines) );
        
    } else {
        $code = 'wp-config.php not found';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Q Studio and my own research, I found that exploding with PHP_EOL worked. Here is my modified code:

```
function eriWpConfig(){
    $wp_config = FALSE;
    if ( is_readable( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' ) )
        $wp_config = ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php';
    elseif ( is_readable( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php' ) )
        $wp_config = dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php';

    if ( $wp_config ) {
        $string = file_get_contents( $wp_config );
        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
        $modified_lines = [];
        $line_count = 0;
        
        foreach($lines as $line){
            $modified_lines[] = '<span style="color: #ccc;">Line: '.sprintf("%03d", $line_count).' | </span>'.esc_html($line);
            $line_count ++; 
        }
        
        $code = implode('<br>', $modified_lines);
        
    } else {
        $code = 'wp-config.php not found';
    }
    
    echo '<pre class="code"
            >Installation path: ' . ABSPATH
          . "\n\n"
          . $code
          . '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```php
if ( $wp_config ) {         
    
    $string = file_get_contents( $wp_config );         
    $lines = explode('\n', $string);         
        
    $line_count = 0;                  
    
    foreach( $lines as $line ){

        $code .= 'Line: '.$line_count.' | '.$line.'<br />';         

        // iterate count ##
        $line_count ++;      

    }              
    
} else {         
    
    $code = 'wp-config.php not found';     
    
}
```

Comment: Tried this. I added my code above. Perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly, but it's just returning a single "Line 0" at the very beginning.

Comment: you need to validate that $string is a real string and that $lines is an array with data - do this by dumping to the screen - i.e. var_dump( $array ); or to an error log - error_log( var_export( $array, true ) );

Comment: Check updated example.

Comment: Tried what you updated it with. Still just the single line number. This time with no output. I did verify that $string is indeed a string and $line is indeed an array via var_dump.

Comment: Last try - bit late for code juggling!

Comment: Tried that, too. I just posted my answer below. Got it to work with `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`. Thanks for your help, Q Studio!